# Command+DELETE no longer working on Hammerspoon once the app focus switches to another

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I'm now writing my own `init.lua` on Hammerspoon, and would like to remap some of my kews to others. Specifically, I would like to switch backslash key and delete key on my macOS.

However, while the simple delete and backslash works properly, once I switch my app focus to another, type in something there, and go back to the original app, the delete key (actually backslash key as I switched it) gets longer working; instead it deletes the characters in the app before it aborts the focus (i.e. the second to last focused app). But if I type in something there and then try again to delete it, suddenly the deletion works again without any problems.

I wonder why it is suddenly not working; it might be a bug, though. Anyway here is my `init.lua` to switch delete and backslash.

```
local VK_BACKSLASH = 0x2a
local VK_DELETE = 0x33
keyEventtap = hs.eventtap.new({
    hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown
}, function(event)
    local bundleId = string.lower(hs.application.frontmostApplication():bundleID())
    local keyCode = event:getKeyCode()
    local flags = event:getFlags()

    if keyCode == VK_DELETE then
        if flagsMatches(flags, {'shift'}) then
            event:setKeyCode(VK_BACKSLASH)
            event:setFlags({shift=true})
        else
            event:setKeyCode(VK_BACKSLASH)
        end
    elseif keyCode == VK_BACKSLASH then
       event:setKeyCode(VK_DELETE) 
    end
end)

keyEventtap:start()
```

What am I missing here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `keyUp` and `flagsChanged` event to monitor the event tap. So, instead of:

```
keyEventtap = hs.eventtap.new({
    hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown
}, function(event)
```

change to the following:

```
keyEventtap = hs.eventtap.new({
    hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown,
    hs.eventtap.event.types.flagsChanged,
    hs.eventtap.event.types.keyUp
}, function(event)
```

At least now this is working for me.